# ARC and nilling out properties

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

If I want to **potentially** re alloc/init and reuse a property of my class under ARC, how can I destroy the previous instance?

Is it legal to call `self.myProperty = nil;` and then later re alloc and init the same property?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
 self.myProperty = nil;
 self.myProperty = [PropertyClass new]; // or [[PropertyClass alloc] init]
```

will do what you want. If `self` is the only thing holding on (retaining) the instance, nilling it out will also call `dealloc` instance method for the class of `myProperty`.

Comment: "Nilling out will also call dealloc" - not always, it depends if this was the only `strong` reference to the object

Comment: excellent, I will mark as correct as soon as I am able. Regards, John

Comment: "on the class of myProperty" - nope. `dealloc` is a method on an instance of `PropertyClass`. `myProperty` will hold a reference to an instance of this class. You are not calling `dealloc` on a class

Comment: @Paul.s good point, in this instance there is only one strong reference to the object.

Comment: I've clarified my answer as, yes you're correct I meant if `self` was the only retaining instance.

Comment: @Paul.s but the dealloc method of `PropertyClass` will be called. That method is in the `PropertyClass` class.

Comment: The way you have worded your answer sounds like you are going to call a class method called `dealloc`, which is not what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You can make the property to nil always when the reference is no more needed. 
 When allocating the object it is not necessary to keep nil.

**Reason behind:** when the pointer is trying to point different location for the if there are no other reference to old location that **old object will be deallocated**.